Mistake in Integrating $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} ‫‪\,\mathrm{d}x‬$ Using Partial Fraction Decomposition
I want to calculate $\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}  ‫‪\,\mathrm{d}x‬‬$ by decomposing $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ into partial fractions:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}  ‫‪\,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{1}{2}\int (\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1+x}) \, \mathrm{d}x \\ &= \frac{1}{2} (\ln \lvert 1-x \rvert + \ln \lvert 1+x \rvert) + c \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \ln \lvert 1-x^2 \rvert + c
\end{align}
However, I believe this result is incorrect. For $x \in (-1,1)$ we can omit the absolute values and when differentiating the result, we obtain:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{2} = -\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$
which does not match the original integrand $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$.
I know that using a different method such as $x = \tanh(\theta)$ yields the correct result, $\tanh^{-1}(x) + c_1$; but I want to know what is my mistake in using partial fraction decomposition?

$\int \frac{1}{1-x}dx = -\ln|1-x|$

You're missing a negative:
$$
\int \frac{1}{1 - x} \mathrm{d}x = -\ln|1 - x| + C
$$
